# SystemStackError (stack level too deep) using Active model Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, serialization

Any idea how I can implement active_mode_serializer in a has_many through association.

I have three models:

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :menu_details, inverse_of: :menu, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :foods, through: :menu_details
end

class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :menu_details
    has_many :menu, through: :menu_details
ends

class MenuDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :menu
    belongs_to :food
end
```

active model serializer

```
class MenuSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :price
  has_many :menu_details
  has_many :foods
end

class MenuDetailSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id

  has_one :menu
  has_one :food
end

class FoodSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id

  has_many :menu_details
  has_many :menu

end
```

I getting this error always:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 24ms

SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
 app/controllers/menus_controller.rb:7:in `all'
```

Comment: Am I at the right structure of my serializer or no? that's why I got that error. I don't know how to work with it in `has_many through`.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: the answer below is relevant to AMS 0.8. There are better ways to do this in more recent versions.**

You can't have two serializers that `has_many` / `has_one` each other. The fix is to create a "short" serializer for each model to be used inside of a related serializer.

For example,

```
class MenuSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :price
  has_many :menu_details, serializer: MenuDetailShortSerializer
  has_many :foods, serializer: FoodShortSerializer
end

class MenuDetailShortSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
end

class FoodShortSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
end
```

Comment: What are the 'better ways to do this' in v9?